# Devise Setup for Ruby on Rails API with Angular 2 (JS app)

Tags: angular, devise, rails-api

I am using Rails API with Angular 2 JS App. Can anyone suggest the best way to setup devise API for this app?

Comment: check out https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/toll

Comment: you can try https://github.com/rjurado01/rails_jwt_auth

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `devise_token_auth`

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

The above page provide all the information you need.

It is built over `deivse` and has library for AngularJS and AngularJS2.